# chmod / chown hfs+ Volume

Tags: mac, chmod, hfs

I have just saved some data from a crashed PC to my external HD, which is a HFS+ Volume using Ubuntu live (regular copy no dd). 
Now I am lost: I don't have any privileges in the Folder i copied on my Macbook. I tried changing it using chmod and chown, both as regular user and as root, but I always get a "operation not permitted". The owner for all those files is "999".

It worked to set it to ignore Ownership.

Comment: Are these files locked (you can see this in *Get Info* dialog)?

Comment: They are not. I can't even click the locked checkbox. It's greyed out.

Comment: Maybe try verifying/repairing in Disk Utility? Ignore ownership on the external drive and copy again?

Comment: I tried to repair permissions using diskutil but the option is greyed out. I can't copy the files again because the drive the came from crashed.

Comment: Have you tried to set the volume to ignore ownership/permissions?